# sub application and virtual directory file permissions

Tags: iis-7

I have a website setup in IIS7, `exampledomain.com`.

Under the application `exampledomain.com` lives a sub application `cms`.

In a rather convoluted way, we have content in our cms system in this sub-app, under `cms\content\{generatedfoldername}`.

So to access an image in this content, the full URL would be `http://www.exampledomain.com/cms/cms/content/{generatedfoldername}/image.jpg`, (yes, cms twice...) and this works just fine.

Now, we have a virtual directory under the parent website, called `stuff` which points at the `content` of the cms. So I should be able to get to the image using the url `http://www.exampledomain.com/stuff/{generatedfoldername}/image.jpg`.

Unfortunately this gives a server 500 error "*There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed*."

Whilst you do have to log into the cms system to access any of the admin pages within, I don't think the image files are protected by login, or else the first example URL wouldn't work, right? Also it's a server 500 error, rather than a 403.

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious here- will the virtual directory be using the permissions defined in the parent application, or the subapplication to which it is pointing? Or is there some other permissions I may have missed?

Sorry, that was a bit long, thanks for reading all the way down here! (I also must point out that I'm pretty new to the server management stuff.)

edit: also, we have

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

specified in the webconfig of the parent app, so it's hopefully not the issue described in this [config file hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx#conflicts_between_settings_on_virtual_and_physical_paths) article.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, similar structure in website and looking for an answer to this as well. I have a top level cms type application that uses a virtual directory to other "sub" sites. In the web editor I'm using all the images won't show up. This works fine in II6 with same structure.

Comment: unfortunately I never found a solution to this, I think we ended up using the unaliased folder name. Hopefully you'll find a solution, make sure to post it here if you do!